# Are $C^k[0,1]$, with the $C^k$ norm, distinct as Banach spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Are the $C^k[0,1]$ (k times differentiable real valued functions on the interval), with the $C^k$ norm, distinct as Banach spaces?

I know $C^k[0,1] \cong \mathbb{R}^k \oplus C^0[0,1]$, but I think this isomorphism is at best a homeomorphism, and not a isometry. It's not clear to me how to compare the different $\mathbb{R}^k \oplus C^0[0,1]$ for varying $k$. Is it possible for $C^0[0,1]$ to "absorb" copies of $\mathbb{R}$, maybe via some good description of $C^0$?

Just curious.

Comment: As I recall it is closer to being a product of $k+1$ copies of $C^0$. It's not exactly that, either, but it's more like that.

Comment: Whether it's an isometry depends on the norms you choose. One of the standard norms on $C^k([0,1])$ is $$\lVert f\rVert = \sum_{n = 0}^{k-1} \lvert f^{(n)}(0)\rvert + \lVert f^{(k)}\rVert_{\infty},$$ then taking the sum-norm on $\mathbb{R}^k \oplus C^0([0,1])$ gets you an isometry.

Comment: @Ian the map is via Taylors theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. I agree it is an isometry in that case. Do you happen to know if $\mathbb{R} \oplus C^0$ and $C^0$, with the norm $|x| + sup f$ and $sup f$ respectively, are distinct Banach spaces?

Comment: If I _knew_ that, I would have posted an answer. I strongly suspect they aren't isomorphic, but I don't see a distinguishing property yet.

Comment: Just an idea: Is $\mathbb R \oplus\mathbb R^2$ (where $\mathbb R^n$ is endowed with the maximum norm and $\oplus$ with the sum of the norms) isometric to a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$? The unit ball of $\mathbb R \oplus\mathbb R^2$ has 6 extreme points but I don't know about subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: Perhaps even simpler: At least for real valued functions the unit ball of $C^0$ has only two extreme points but the one of $\mathbb R \oplus C^0$ has (at least) four.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unit ball of $C^0([0,1])$ has only two extreme points (the constant functions with value $\pm 1$) but the one of $\mathbb R \oplus C^0([0,1])$
with the norm $|t|+ \|f\|_\infty$ has (at least) four. Therefore, the spaces are not isometric.