# isomorphism between $C[0,1]$ and $C^1[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is space $C[0,1]$ with norm $\parallel f \parallel=\max|f(x)|$ (space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$) isomorphic to space $C^1[0,1]$ with norm $\parallel f \parallel=\max|f(x)|+\max|f'(x)|$ (space of continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$) ? Under isomorphism I mean continuous linear bijective operator between these two spaces (and also the inverse is continuous). If yes, is there any explicit example of such isomorphism ? Thank you very much for Your answers.

Comment: Which topologies do you have in mind for $C[0, 1]$ and $C^1[0, 1]$?

Comment: $f\mapsto f' + f(0)$ is an isomorphism provided you use a norm on $C^1$ that makes this work.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Doesn't the mapping $f(t)=ct-c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ show that your mapping is not injective?

Comment: @user93559: That's right, I guess I need to map $C^1\to C\oplus\mathbb C$, $f\mapsto (f',f(0))$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: This map is clearly an isomorphism (by the open mapping theorem), but then it still remains to show that $C[0,1]\oplus\mathbb{C}$ and $C[0,1]$ are isomorphic.

Comment: The question was answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615752/are-ck0-1-with-the-ck-norm-distinct-as-banach-spaces/1618103#1618103

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, this boils down to showing that $C[0,1]\oplus\mathbb C\cong C[0,1]$. This works because $C[0,1]$ has a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) $g_n$; in fact, I want to work with specifically the [Faber-Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet#Haar_system_on_the_unit_interval_and_related_systems). With respect to this basis, partial sums (up to $N=2^n$) of an expansion $f=\sum a_n g_n$ are piecewise linear interpolations of $f$ at the points $k2^{-n}$, and the coefficients $a_n$ are given by these values of $f$. In particular, $\|f\|=\sup |a_n|$.

It is now clear that $(f,a)\mapsto ag_0 + \sum a_n g_{n+1}$ has the desired properties.

Comment: It looks like this is in contradiction with the link posted by jochen in the last comment of the question.

Comment: @Renart: The linked question is about *isometries,* while the OP asks about isomorphisms.

Comment: yes you're right, my bad !